# How to Browse files in server side

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my admin panel i have input field to select file and upload it , but the problem is i want to change this , when i click on the input field i want to select the file from a folder in server side.

**for example** this is the normal input field :

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

When i click on it it will show my local files , Well i want the same but when i click on it to show my server files and select a specific file .

is that possible ?

If someone can help me with the way & **controller side** i appreciate that.

Thanks

Comment: No its not possible. And it makes no sense to select a file from the server and then upload it to the server since its already on the server. What are your trying to do?

Comment: @stephen-muecke I'm uploading large files in the server , and i want to browse the folder i uploaded the files there to just move them from folder to secure folder and get the path of the file

Comment: @vishu-minhas what the security about ! if the admin access the admin panel !!

Comment: Still not clear what your wanting to do, but you have a controller method that returns the file names in your folder and display them in a view